# Movie with crystal spike travelling up an arm?

Tags: story-identification

I have this childhood memory of a fairly cheesy SF movie where a person comes into contact with some kind of crystal, and it goes into his arm near the wrist.  You can then see the triangular shape travelling up his arm under the skin, as he watches in horror.

I think this happens twice in the movie.

I know this isn't a lot to go on, but it was a striking scene (to me, anyway), so I thought it might be identifiable.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't talking about the Matrix? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2MSF35IxVE see time code 01:55.

Comment: @Jack B Nimble: Definitely not. I'm very familiar with The Matrix. This is much older (maybe 20-30 years now?), and in my vague memory, much cheesier. Also, this was a very definite triangle shape, traveling just *under* the skin.

Comment: Odd that this was marked as a duplicate.  It's got the same answer, but it's a very different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly [Galaxy of Terror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_of_Terror)?
I recall something like what you ask about, although the worm rape scene is what is most remembered. Here is a longer synopsis: [movie-with-crystal-spike](http://mmmmmovies.blogspot.com/2008/08/galaxy-of-terror-1981-or-in-space-no.html)

Comment: That guys blog is almost as time-icidal as tvtropes! I think I lost a good half-hour clicking links to reviews for other terrible-yet-awesome movies.

Comment: Just like describes on the link you provide, I thought I remembered him cutting off his own arm, too!  I think this has *got* to be it, though I don't remember the worm scene (and, as a teenager, you would think I would.)  However, I suspect I probably was watching a "cleaned up" version on cable.  Without viewing to prove one way or the other, I'm going to have to give this answer the prize until proven otherwise.

Comment: I watched it in release and walked out right after the worm scene -- my gf was highly offended. That and the crystal spike scene is all I remember.

Comment: Just verified this one!  Thanks!