# What 70s film has astronauts entering an old alien building?

Tags: story-identification, movie

It is about astronauts entering an old alien building (which may have been a pyramid).

In this building some of the astronauts get killed or injured.

When the last astronaut arrives at the center of the building, he finds another guy who says the building was a test designed by old aliens and that the astronaut will be the next God.

Comment: Do you mean a film 70 years old - the 1940s, or a film from the 1970s?  There aren't many in the former timeframe.

Comment: 1970 but I don't know the exactly date.

Comment: Thanks Stark07 for the corrections. I am spanish and the english language...

Comment: Did you actually see this in the 70's, or when did you see it? Did it seem to be originally made in any country and then translated?

Comment: I remember that in 90's in a TV channel.

Comment: Stargate? I believe there was a scene with a pyramid and astronauts.

Comment: duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7369/movie-with-crystal-spike-travelling-up-an-arm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds very much like [**Galaxy of Terror**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_of_Terror), released in 1981. In the film, the crew of a military vessel find themselves stranded on an alien planet and begin exploring the nearby pyramid-like structure. Throughout the course of the film, each crew member is confronted by a physical manifestation of their worst fear. In fact, the movie has become somewhat infamous due to a lengthy scene which depicts one crewmember

> being raped by a giant maggot (her fear is worms).

[image]

At the end of the film, the lone survivor finally makes it to the center of the structure only to find someone he did not expect.

> The Master explains that the pyramid is actually an ancient toy for the children of a long-extinct race, built in order to test their ability to control fear. Cabren kills the Master for allowing his crew to die, but becomes the new Master in his place.

Comment: This sounds like a film i would enjoy :S

Comment: Yes it is the film. Thanks.

Comment: @tres.14159 - glad we were able to help you find it. When you have a chance, click the arrow icon under the voting buttons to accept this answer. That will let future viewers know that it answered your question. And, yeah, this movie used to scare the @#%& out of me when I was a teenager. It probably hasn't aged well but it was pretty scary back in the day.

Answer (score 2):

"Galaxy of Terror" sounds like it fits (I haven't seen it).  Another movie from the 70's where a space crew explores an alien building: **Alien** (1979).

Comment: Yes "Galaxy of Terror" is the film. Thanks.