# Trying to ID an 80's scifi movie what take place on an alien planet with a giant volcano

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I am trying to ID an old scifi/horror movie. It was around the 80's. I saw it on VHS.

The movie takes place on an alien (possible hostile) planet. A group of people landed with a spaceship. There was a massive volcano or mountain with a giant sinkhole.

They descend into the pit which had small holes on the walls. From the holes, a worm-like creature comes out and kill some of the people. Deep underground there was a maze-like place, the crew tries to find something or someone or just escape; I don't remember. There was a huge snail-like creature that "ate" one of the women, but just ate the clothes from her. Later on the rest of the crew find her dead naked.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92365/what-70s-film-has-astronauts-entering-an-old-alien-building

Answer (score 6):

Based on some of the details given, particularly the giant snail monster, I think this movie may be [Galaxy of Terror](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082431/) from 1981.  The volcano mentioned is likely the movie's alien pyramid structure.

From Wikipedia:

> One by one, the members of the mission begin to experience a growing
> sense of dread and terror in the same way the crewman previously
> killed had. Shortly after these experiences begin, each one is
> attacked by some kind of creature that is an expression of basic,
> primal fears -- tentacles, dismembered arms, inanimate objects, giant
> worms, shadowy figures.

The giant worm scene was quite controversial and is described in detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_of_Terror#Taaffe_O%27Connell_and_%22the_worm_scene%22).

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like it might be Roger Corman's *[Galaxy of Terror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_of_Terror)* (1981)

> Without delay, the spaceship Quest blasts off to Morganthus. As it approaches the planet's atmosphere, it suddenly veers out of control; the captain and tech officer are able to make a controlled crash landing on the surface. After recovering from the crash, the mission team leave the Quest to search for survivors.
>
> Crossing the landscape of the planet, they eventually reach the other vessel, where they find evidence that a massacre has taken place. While wrapping up their survey of the ship, a high-strung young member of the team becomes increasingly terrified, despite being reassured by his seniors. A short time later, while he is alone, he is killed by a grotesque creature that immediately vanishes, leaving only his mutilated body for the search team to find.
>
> Back on the ship, the crew discover a giant structure that is the source of the energy that wrecked them. While the captain and two others remain on the Quest, Ilvar and Cabren lead the rest of the crew to explore the structure. One by one, the members of the mission begin to experience a growing sense of dread and terror in the same way the crewman previously killed had. Shortly after these experiences begin, each one is attacked by some kind of creature that is an expression of basic, primal fears -- tentacles, dismembered arms, inanimate objects, giant worms, shadowy figures.
>
> On the Quest, crewman Ranger catches sight of Captain Trantor running through the ship as if being attacked, and on the security cameras he sees her spontaneously combust as she fires a weapon in an airlock. He and the ship's cook join the remaining survivors of the dwindling mission in the pyramid. Ranger begins to feel the terror effect, and is soon attacked by a double. He manages to fend the double off, regains control of himself while doing so, and the double fades away. He finds Cabren, the other remaining survivor, and tells him. Cabren then discovers that the ship's cook is really the Planet Master seen at the beginning of the film. The Master forces Cabren to confront all of the monsters that attacked the others; he does so successfully, and the Master tells him that he has "won the game." The Master then explains that the pyramid is actually an ancient toy for the children of a long-extinct race, built in order to test their ability to control fear. Angered, Cabren kills the Master's previous host body, but as the Master himself cannot die, Cabren becomes his new host.

The "snail" is likely the infamous "[worm scene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_of_Terror#Taaffe_O%27Connell_and_%22the_worm_scene%22)".

> The commentary on the 2010 Shout! Factory DVD release includes R.J. Kizer, one of three editors of the film. Kizer reveals that the originally scripted version of O'Connell's "Dameia" character would see her die topless while being stripped and consumed by a monster. Producer Roger Corman, however, had promised financial backers of the movie a sex scene involving O'Connell. This led to Corman re-writing her death so that Dameia would be confronted by an "id monster" from her own mind, in this case a 12-foot (3.7 m) long maggot complete with slime and tentacles. The re-write included full nudity and far more explicit sexual content, including simulated sexual intercourse during which Dameia, lying underneath the giant worm and covered in excreted slime, can be seen and heard reacting first with terror, then forced sexual arousal, to the monster raping her. Helpless and betrayed by her own mind and body, Dameia perishes as she's driven to a fatally intense orgasm.

### Trailer (naked body visible at 1:06)

Comment: Yes! Thats it! I was 8 years old back then, so my memories about this is almost nothing 

Comment: @vadonka: Excellent. Feel free to accept either my or Dosco's answer. We basically came in at the same time.