# Movie with flying eel-like creature and some weird gooey alien

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I saw this movie back in the 90s. I suppose it was a horror movie, but there was nudity. I remember a blonde actress, who was chained, clothes were stripped and swallowed from head down by a creature that looks like a gooey alien. I also remember seeing something like flying eels. That's all I remember. I saw it in 1996, but the film could've been released in the early 90s or late 80s too.

Comment: The eels make me think of _[The Langoliers](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/stephen_kings_the_langoliers)_ but I don't remember the gooey alien.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this could be [From Beyond](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091083/).

Released in 1986, so that fits, has a lot of nudity and the blonde actress gets tied up with chains and leather straps and so on considerably more often than the plot might require.

It's about a scientist who creates a machine which resonates at a frequency which enables humans and other dimensional beings to interact.

The "flying eels" would be extra-dimensional creatures a bit like fish that swim around in the air when the machine is active. As the plot progresses, the scientist becomes more and more of a gooey alien thing and tries to swallow the woman.

I can't find any clips of the "eels" on youtube, unfortunately, but here's a trailer:

Comment: Naturally, the original short story by Lovecraft is miles better than the film adaptation:  https://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/fb.aspx

Comment: Thank you, kind sir. This was precisely what I saw. I remember bits and pieces but I was able to recollect it.

Answer (score 2):

The gooey animal stripping the actress and swallowing her makes me think of *[Galaxy of Terror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_of_Terror)* as per my answer to [Trying to ID an 80's scifi movie what take place on an alien planet with a giant volcano](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/260499/23243)

> Without delay, the spaceship Quest blasts off to Morganthus. As it approaches the planet's atmosphere, it suddenly veers out of control; the captain and tech officer are able to make a controlled crash landing on the surface. After recovering from the crash, the mission team leave the Quest to search for survivors.
>
> Crossing the landscape of the planet, they eventually reach the other vessel, where they find evidence that a massacre has taken place. While wrapping up their survey of the ship, a high-strung young member of the team becomes increasingly terrified, despite being reassured by his seniors. A short time later, while he is alone, he is killed by a grotesque creature that immediately vanishes, leaving only his mutilated body for the search team to find.
>
> Back on the ship, the crew discover a giant structure that is the source of the energy that wrecked them. While the captain and two others remain on the Quest, Ilvar and Cabren lead the rest of the crew to explore the structure. One by one, the members of the mission begin to experience a growing sense of dread and terror in the same way the crewman previously killed had. Shortly after these experiences begin, each one is attacked by some kind of creature that is an expression of basic, primal fears -- tentacles, dismembered arms, inanimate objects, giant worms, shadowy figures.

....

> The commentary on the 2010 Shout! Factory DVD release includes R.J. Kizer, one of three editors of the film. Kizer reveals that the originally scripted version of O'Connell's "Dameia" character would see her die topless while being stripped and consumed by a monster. Producer Roger Corman, however, had promised financial backers of the movie a sex scene involving O'Connell. This led to Corman re-writing her death so that Dameia would be confronted by an "id monster" from her own mind, in this case a 12-foot (3.7 m) long maggot complete with slime and tentacles. The re-write included full nudity and far more explicit sexual content, including simulated sexual intercourse during which Dameia, lying underneath the giant worm and covered in excreted slime, can be seen and heard reacting first with terror, then forced sexual arousal, to the monster raping her. Helpless and betrayed by her own mind and body, Dameia perishes as she's driven to a fatally intense orgasm.

The other linked question mentions "worms" flying out of holes in the wall, which would track with your memory of flying eels.

### Trailer (naked body visible at 1:06)

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92365/what-70s-film-has-astronauts-entering-an-old-alien-building

Comment: And, upon finding a full version of the film, the creature that consumes Dameia is much more maggot-like than the descriptions indicated.

Comment: That sounds like a movie that I'll enjoy. Thank you.